# Como formatar fonte e tamanho do texto em uma impressora térmica usando Java

Tags: java, impressora

Bom, estou desenvolvendo um programa para uma pizzaria e preciso imprimir os pedidos com os respectivos sabores de pizza, porém com formatação correta, letras maiores e tal, a padrão é muito pequena para minhas necessidades, segue o código que estou usando

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class Impressao {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        PrintStream ps = null;
        try{ 
            fos = new FileOutputStream("LPT1:");
        } catch (Exception ex) {}
        try {
            ps = new PrintStream(fos);
        } 
        catch (Exception exception) {} 

        ps.print("Coloque aqui o que você quer");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa ler a documentação da impressora, para alterar a formatação e outros afins em geral, existem códigos que devem ser enviados para a impressora.
Esses códigos podem variar entre as mais diferentes impressoras.

Comment: Enviei um código que aumentaria o tamanho da fonte mas nada aconteceu

Comment: Acredito que você precise enviar estes códigos como hexadecimais, verifique se isso acontece.